# JSON.parse error in browsers other than Chrome

Tags: javascript, json, sharepoint

I am having an issue with parsing fetched JSON data when accessing from browsers other than Chrome. Firefox returns the most detailed error: "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data". In some cases, the code will work in other browsers when hosted in my local node.js development environment but then only in Chrome when the files are hosted by SharePoint. In an example I uploaded to github pages, it works in Chrome and not in Firefox, et. al.

```
    function loadData() {
      return fetch('./data.txt').then((response) => response.json());
    }

    function loadMoreData() {
      return fetch('./moredata.txt').then((response) => response.json());
    }

    function loadAllData(){ 
      return Promise.all([loadData(),loadMoreData()]);
    }

    loadAllData().then( ([data, moredata]) => {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(moredata);
    });
```

data.txt:

```
[
  {"emp_id":"90176","labor_code":"500"},
  {"emp_id":"90202","labor_code":"500"},
  {"emp_id":"90678","labor_code":"400"},
  {"emp_id":"91245","labor_code":"300"},
  {"emp_id":"91304","labor_code":"200"},
  {"emp_id":"94377","labor_code":"100"},
  {"emp_id":"94398","labor_code":"200"}
]
```

moredata.txt:

```
[
  {"emp_id": "90176","hire_year": "1999"},
  {"emp_id": "90202","hire_year": "2010"},
  {"emp_id": "90678","hire_year": "2005"},
  {"emp_id": "91245","hire_year": "1994"},
  {"emp_id": "91304","hire_year": "1995"},
  {"emp_id": "94377","hire_year": "1995"},
  {"emp_id": "94398","hire_year": "1998"}
]
```

Here is the location of the github data where it works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but not in Firefox when I transfer the files to be hosted by SharePoint:

Demo (see console.log): https://allenblair.github.io/fetchissue/

Source Files: [https://github.com/allenblair/fetchissue/](https://github.com/allenblair/fetchissue)

Is there something in my code that needs to be different?

Comment: I see no error in Firefox. Two arrays are logged to the console.

Comment: Yes, I just realized my error. That case looks fine on github, but when transferring the same files to SharePoint, it produces the error. Unfortunately I don't have a public sharepoint server to demo the error.

Comment: I edited the question to correct.

Comment: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: So look at the file in the console for Firefox and see what is in it. Next instead read the `console.log(escape(response.text())` and see what is in it. My guess is there might be some hidden characters in it...

Comment: The files are valid JSON and your code runs correctly in chrome, IE and firefox. So the issue is not with your code. Have you checked that the response in sharepoint is actually still a JSON string? Depending on your sharepoint, it might already be parsed into an array.

Comment: can you try it as `fetch('./data.txt',{ headers: { "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose","accept": "application/json;odata=verbose", } }).then((response) => response.json());`

Comment: `console.log(escape(response.text())` in the place of `response.json()` produces "%5Bobject%20Promise%5D" (without surrounding quotes) in Chrome and Firefox

Comment: @AllenBlair That's a promise. You need to do `response.text().then(t => console.log(t))`

Comment: @JLRishe (and epascarello) Thanks for the help. I think we are on to something now. Chrome returned the json as expected, Firefox returned an html page that looks to be the "you're logged out" page from our security gateway.

Comment: I bypassed our security gateway by logging into the network using VPN and now I get "401 UNAUTHORIZED" in Firefox. Chrome still returns json as expected. It must not be seeing credentials when using Firefox.

Comment: @AllenBlair Try including `credentials: 'include'` in the `fetch` options.

Comment: @JLRishe Thank you greatly!!! That did it. I updated and tested my actual app as well and that is what it needed to now work in Chrome, Firefox, and Edge. Thanks for all the help. What's the best thing to do with this question now? I'm new to asking questions here even though I use the site a lot.

Comment: @AllenBlair If you think there is a salvageable question and answer out of this that would be helpful to other people (I kind of suspect that there isn't), you could edit your question and title, and then provide an answer to your own question in the answer area. Otherwise, the thing to do would be to just delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

this was caused by the fetch in firefox that returns 401 not authorized
so Yes thank you @JLRishe
we have to add `credentials: 'include'` in the header

I use it with react in SharePoint 2016

```
componentDidMount() {


    let headers = {
        method: 'GET',
        credentials: 'include',
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
        },
        mode: 'cors',
        cache: 'default'
    };

    let siteURL = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl;
    let apiPath = siteURL + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('linksfooter')/items?$select=Title,LinkFooterColonne,LinkFooterContent,LinkFooterPosCol";



    fetch(apiPath, headers)
        .then(
            res => res.json()
        ).then(
            (d) => {
                // console.log('fetched data = ', d)
                let footerItemsResult = d.d.results;
                let categories = footerItemsResult.map(item => item.LinkFooterColonne).filter(function (v, i, a) {
                    return a.indexOf(v) === i
                })
                // console.log('footerItemsResult = ', footerItemsResult)
                this.setState({
                    isLoaded: true,
                    footerItems: footerItemsResult,
                    categories: categories
                });
            },
            (error) => {
                this.setState({
                    isLoaded: false,
                    error
                });
            }
        )
}
```